# Angular js color-picker

Tags: angularjs, cordova, popup, color-picker

I use this tutorial [angular-bootstrap-colorpicker](https://github.com/buberdds/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker/tree/2.0) to include a color-picker from angularjs.

I added this code `<input colorpicker="hex" class="span2" value="" type="text" ng-model="your_model" /`>

In my page home.html ,it's fine I found this result :

[image: palette1]

but when I copy this code inside my popup

```
var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({

              template: ' Nom Categorie<input type="text" ng-model="data.nomcategorie">   <br> Type Categorie  <input type="text" ng-model="data.typecategorie" > <br><input colorpicker="hex" class="span2" value="" type="text" ng-model="your_model" /><img ng-model="data.imgURI" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{imgURI}}">',

              title: 'Ajouter Categorie',

//            subTitle: 'Please use normal things',

              scope: $scope,

              buttons: [{

                 text: 'Cancel'

              }, {

                 text: '<b>Save</b>'}
```

always I found a color red ,and empty value in input

[image: palette2]

What can I do? Help me please.

Comment: I'd say that your popup doesn't have access to `$scope` variable or you have typo in model name. What happens when you select color?

Comment: nothing ,the color does not change and this popup of color has disappeared

Comment: So it might be problem with event handlers as well (popup consumes click and doesnt pass it to color picker), with a raw code like I can't do much, if you could do plunker or jsfiddle it would be easier to debug